# I found that there is an error import path in saved_model.go

Tags: tensorflow, go

problem:

in github:

```golang
import (
    "runtime"
    "unsafe"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"

    tfpb "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core"
)
```

what's this(tfpb "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core") ?
I cannot find it in anywhere , so can my program
How can I solve this problem

there is details:
today I try to install tensorflow for Go and execute it, I use this cmd:

`go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go`

then i test tf for go:

`go test github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go`

(according with this site: [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_go))

but i got this message:

> cannot find package "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core" in any of:
>   /home/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core (from $GOROOT)
>
> ### /home/go_work/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core (from $GOPATH)

then i visit github then i cannot find this path , How can I solve this problem？
thanks for you guys.!

Comment: i can found tensorflow path in GOPATH(my GOPATH is /home/go_work)

Comment: Much better, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at the similar issue on Github: [23257](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23257)

So, there's no proper fix out there which is documented, until then you can try this out. I resolved my error using the following way:

1. Run `go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go`

```
package github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core: cannot find package "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core" in any of:
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.5/libexec/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/subhamsarkar/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/genop/internal/proto/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core (from $GOPATH)
```

2. Above get surely fails to find the said package, but the repo is already cloned to your `GOPATH`
3. `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go`
4. `git checkout r1.11`

Now again run,

5. `go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go`

> Reason: [Discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23257#issuecomment-433751410)

Also, I believe you have installed the `TensorFlow C library` which is required for the `TensorFlow Go package`.

*Note*: I tested on

> **OS**: MacOSX 10.15.2
>   **Go version**: go1.13.5 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 3):

Since this issue isn't getting fixed, I decided to maintain a fork: https://github.com/galeone/tensorflow

```
go get github.com/galeone/tensorflow/tensorflow/go@r2.4-go
```

You can also use [tfgo](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo) that depends on the fork and it allows a simplified usage of the Go bindings:

```
go get github.com/galeone/tfgo
```