# Not able to get tensorflow-go

Tags: tensorflow, go, machine-learning

Im trying to make api for my ML model but Im not able to install the go package for this.
Im getting this error:

```
go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go
```

```
package github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/core_protos_go_proto: cannot find package "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/core_protos_go_proto" in any of:
```

```
    /usr/lib/go-1.10/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/core_protos_go_proto (from $GOROOT)
    /home/user/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/core_protos_go_proto (from $GOPATH)
```

So, can u help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I found that there is an error import path in saved\_model.go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59452621/i-found-that-there-is-an-error-import-path-in-saved-model-go)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59452621/i-found-that-there-is-an-error-import-path-in-saved-model-go/59453744#59453744

Refer my answer there. It'll solve your issue!

Answer (score 0):

That's a well-known issue that isn't going to be fixed (it seems).

So I decided to maintain a fork that fixes the problem https://github.com/galeone/tensorflow

```
go get github.com/galeone/tensorflow/tensorflow/go@r2.4-go
```

You can also use [tfgo](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo) that depends on the fork and it allows a simplified usage of the Go bindings:

```
go get github.com/galeone/tfgo
```